# How to reinitiate all properties in a static class in c#

Tags: c#, class, static

```html
public static class MySampleClass
{
     public static string sampleProperty1
     {
            get { return GetValue("sampleProperty1"); }
     }
     public static string GetValue(string Key)
    {
       // Here is the code to get value from table based Key.
          return Key;
    }
}
```

I have many static properties in MySampleClass like SampleProperty1...
once I have set values for the properties, I'm not able to reset the values to same properties.

Comment: Which language is this ?

Comment: c#, Mvc application.

Comment: How do  you set values for your properties?  It looks like sampleProperty1 will always have the value, "sampleProperty1".  What's the purpose of GetValue?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't. Static properties is almost every time is a code smell, especially mutable. Make them non-static and use instances of your class.

In this case you can implement this class as every new instance initialized with new portion of values from some `table`. And you won't have a problem of reinitialization - just create new instance of this type and it'll be initialized with fresh new values.

---

Your current implementation doesn't require reinitialization - the properties of `MySampleClass` always get actual value from `table`. If that instance of `table` is outdated, get fresh one and replace old one with this new one - after that properties of `MySampleClass` will return fresh values.